# Changing datatype UInt64 to Float in Julia time

Tags: julia

I am trying to calculate running time of a function in Julia. For example:

```
time = tic(); 7^12000000; toc()
```

I want to get the result as float. Type of "time" is Uint64, can anyone help me to convert it to Float64?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `tic` and `toc` got removed in Julia 1.0 (on 0.7 they work but throw a deprecation warning). What I propose below works on Julia 0.6, 0.7 and 1.0.

You can use:

- `@elapsed` macro from Base which returns time taken in seconds as `Float64` (which, in particular, returns compilation time and run time on the first call of the benchmarked function but only runt time on consecutive runs as the called function will already be compiled)
- `@belapsed` macro from BenchmarkTools.jl which returns the same but is more sophisticated (see BenchmarkTools.jl for details, but the main difference is that it runs your function many times and reports minimum observed time)

Here is an example:

```
julia> @elapsed sum(rand(10^6)) # includes compilation time
0.182671045

julia> @elapsed sum(rand(10^6)) # benchmarked functions are already precompiled
0.007848933

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @belapsed sum(rand(10^6)) # minimum time from many runs
0.006249196
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. tic() and toc() do not exist in Julia. Use the macro @time.

```
julia> @time Float64(UInt(7^12000))
  0.000048 seconds (7 allocations: 208 bytes)
6.871777734182465e18
```

Comment: it does exist in Julia. I have tried it.
I can use @time as well.

My question is I want to plot running time of a function if I change some variables.  Hence I want to convert the datatype to float first. How can I convert the datatype?